# Angular API Proxy Routing - Wildcard not working

Tags: angular, http, proxy

When introducing a wildcard into my proxy.conf.js routing no longer works.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
      context: [
        "/fi/ameribor/*"
      ],
      target: "http://localhost:10000",
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  ]
  
  module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

the get method is as follows:

```
getAmeriborRates(term:string, start:string, end:string):Observable<Rate[]>{

    let queryParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('Term', term)
      .set('Start', start)
      .set('End', end);

    console.log(queryParams.toString());

    return this.http.get<Rate[]>('/fi/ameribor');
    //return this.http.get<Rate[]>('/fi/ameribor', {params:queryParams});
  }
```

Everything works fine when the context is set to "fi/ameribor" but I get a bad request when using a wildcard because the redirection to my API url only seems to work when there is an exact match:

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/fi/ameribor', ok: false, …}

Answer (score 1):

```
  return this.http.get<Rate[]>('/fi/ameribor/');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote `context`, the routing will match any path starting with `/fi/ameribor/`, but you're looking for path `/fi/ameribor`. There's a "/" missing at the end

Comment: This does not fix the problem unfortunately. context: ["/fi/ameribor/"] still does not match either "fi/ameribor" or "/fi/ameribor" with the httpParams set ie. "/fi/ameribor?Term=overnight&Start=&End="

Comment: Update - changing the context to "/fi/" does route correctly when getting 'fi/ameribor' but when called passing the httpParams as a parameter to the get method does not work - Very confused!

Comment: Just to clarify context = "/fi/": ```return this.http.get<Rate[]>('/fi/ameribor');``` works, ```return this.http.get<Rate[]>('/fi/ameribor', {params:queryParams});``` does not work

Comment: What error are you getting now? A 404?

Comment: Based on the error message you provided, it seems like the request is being sent to `http://localhost:4200/fi/ameribor` instead of being proxied to `http://localhost:10000/fi/ameribor`. This could be happening because the `queryParams` are not being correctly appended to the URL. Can you try looking at the value of `queryParams.toString()` in your console before making the request to see if the query parameters are being correctly serialized?